# How do I refer to a work rather than the authors with an APA citation?

Tags: citation

The APA Publication manual recognizes two kinds of in-text citations, *parenthetical* and *narrative*. They are characterized as follows:

> In parenthetical citations, the author name and publication date (or equivalent information; see Section 9.12) appear in parentheses. In narrative citations, this information is incorporated into the text as part of the sentence. (§8.11)

As far as I can see, in all their examples of narrative citations, the last names that occur outside the parentheses are taken as referring to the *authors* of the cited works.  For example, one might write

> Salas and D’Agostino (2020) examine several aspects of this problem.

which would mean something like ’Salas and D'Agostino (in their work published in 2020) examine several aspects of this problem.

My question is, within APA style, can I also use a narrative citation to refer to the *work* rather than the authors of that work?  For example, could I write:

> Salas and D'Agostino (2020) is the most complete treatment of this problem in the literature.

Obviously here I would be referring to the work, not the authors, hence ‘is’ rather than ‘are‘.  Is this also correct?  And if not, what do I write if I want the subject of my sentence to refer to the cited work rather than the authors?

(In other author-date citation systems I am familiar with, I could refer to the work by omitting the parentheses, like this:

> Salas and D'Agostino 2020 is the most complete treatment of this problem in the literature.

This seems logical to me.  But unfortunately I find that APA style does not allow for this; hence my question.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's not really about the English language.

Comment: OK, sorry to bother you folks. I saw some other questions on here about citation and figured that this might be the right place, but maybe I was wrong.  I do note however that the APA Publication Manual is primarily a manual of English style.

Comment: It would be fine on our meta site: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this type of question is fine. Since this type of citation is integrated into the structure of a sentence, it is manifestly about English usage. (I don't mean to imply that questions about footnotes wouldn't be fine. But that is a separate issue.)

Answer (score 2):

This question is not just about the APA style, but more generally about in-text citations within the author-year style of citation. Here is what *The Chicago Manual of Style* says on the subject:

> ## 15: Author-Date References
>
> ### 15.28: Syntactic considerations with text citations
>
> An author-date citation is a form of bibliographic shorthand that
> corresponds to a fully cited work; it does not refer to a person. …  A
> locution such as “in Smith 2009,” though technically proper, is
> usually best avoided except as part of a parenthetical citation. To
> help readers identify the source citation, prefer “in Smith (2009)”
> or, for example, “in Smith’s (1999) study.”

So, this is fine:

*Salas and D'Agostino (2020) is the most complete treatment of this problem in the literature.*

But arguably, this is better:

*The work of Salas and D'Agostino (2020) is the most complete treatment of this problem in the literature.*